# How to formally show $\mathbb R$ with the standard topology is finer than $\mathbb R$ with the finite complement topology?

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

We only consider $\mathbb R$. In the finite complement topology, only finite sets are closed whereas in the standard topology, finite sets are closed but not the only closed sets. For example $[0,1]$ is closed in the standard topology, but is infinite. So, the standard topology is "larger".

This is my intuition for saying the standard topology is finer but how can I go about showing this formally? That is, by showing that a basis element for the finite complement topology contains a basis element from the standard topology.

What is a general basis element for the finite complement topology?

Comment: @ Al Jeber: Is there any topology on $\mathbb R$ which is finer than the standard topology besides descete topology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There’s no reason to look at bases for either topology: you know exactly what *every* open set is in the finite complement topology. Let $\tau$ be the finite complement topology on $\Bbb R$. If $U\in\tau$, then either $U=\varnothing$, which is certainly open in the usual topology, or $\Bbb R\setminus U$ is finite. Let $F=\Bbb R\setminus U$. The usual topology is $T_1$, so $F$ is closed in the usual topology, and therefore $U=\Bbb R\setminus F$ is open in the usual topology. This shows that $\tau$ is at least as coarse as the usual topology. And $(0,1)$ is open in the usual topology but not in $\tau$, so in fact $\tau$ is strictly coarser than the usual topology on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I thought the usual topology was finer. Maybe you mean to say strictly coarser in the last sentence?

Comment: @AlJebr: I did indeed; mind went one way, and fingers went the other. Thanks!

Comment: Since the finite complement topology on $\mathbb R$ is coarser than the standard topology, can we say the finite complement topology is a subspace of the standard topology?

Comment: @AlJebr: No. $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ if $Y\subseteq X$, and the topology on $Y$ is $\{U\cap Y:U\in\tau\}$, where $\tau$ is the topology on $X$. This subspace topology on $Y$ may not be comparable to $\tau$ at all, neither finer nor coarser.